# Mongodb won't start after adding 2nd net option to mongod.conf file

Tags: replication, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I try to add another net with the its corresponding bind ip and port to my AMI ec2 mongod.conf file so I will be able to create a 2 node replica set but when I run the command "sudo service mongos restart", mongos won't start. Here is my mongos.conf file:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 172.31.90.193 # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 172.31.92.31
#security:

#operationProfiling:

replication:
 replSetName: "Midterm"

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I tried doing this in a vm using vagrant and it worked. Why would be any different in AMI ec2?

**UPDATE:

This is what the security group of one of my instances looks like:
[image]

Comment: this works if I'm setting the replica set on 1 machine but im trying to create a 3 node replica set, meaning that I have 3 VMs and want to make a replica set where there is 1 instance on each machine

Comment: Try this https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mongodb/create-a-mongodb-replica-set/

Comment: the 1st node I made as primary couldn't find the second node to add to the replica set.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the MongoDB running on the second machine from the first machine through mongo shell? If not enable inbound ports in the second machine, check the config file binip as well.

Comment: if you mean ping, I can ping the bindIp of the machines on each other and there is a response

Comment: I altered the inbound security groups of all the nodes so I can ping them now from their instances and I get a response

Comment: Also, add MongoDB ports inbound rule to accept connections.

Comment: does that mean for example, from instance 1 I can ping instance 2 and vice versa?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91280/discussion-between-mani-and-tom-dinh).

Comment: @tomdinh, What is MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: I see two potential issues with your config: (1) you have repeated the `bindIp` section instead of listing multiple comma-separated IPs in a single value and (2) you may be conflating `bindIp` with a firewall setting. The `bindIp` values correspond to which network interfaces `mongod` listens to on the local machine. Unless a single instance has more than one 172.* network interface (i.e. both 172.31.90.193 and 172.31.92.31), this setting is likely incorrect. Related answer on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24590516.